# I want to use java 1.6 with lotus Notes 6.5. Is there a way to do that..? –

Tags: java, path, classpath, lotus-notes

I want to use java 1.6 with lotus Notes 6.5. Is there a way to do that..? –

I wanted to use prabalePrime method of BigInteger class which is available since java 1.4 and above, But Lotus notes 6.5 only supports java 1.3. Is there any way to use higher versions of java say java 1.6 in lotus notes 6.5?

Any help will be great!!

Thanks in Advanace!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade! R6.5 support ended almost 2 years ago.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that..BUt the company for which I am working has no plans upgrading...so no choice...

Comment: You cannot have it both ways. If you want to use the latest (or later) Java you should use the latest (or later) domino. Be sure to factor into your cost estimates the expense of not upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

In short you should upgrade to R8.5. You cannot import the 1.6 JRE into a notes environment seamlessly as the Agent based functionality is wired up to the IBM JVM in Notes, also if you attempt to modify the IBM JVM built into Notes, you will invalidate your company's support and maintenance agreement with IBM. But seeing as you're using R6.5 which is no longer supported, you could give it a go, but this would require an update on every workstation, and you can't guarantee that you won't break anything in the process.

I had to use Kerberos for my company, and the IBM JVM that IBM wired into Notes had some annoying limitations, (typical IBM), so we had to also write for a higher JVM. This is what we did.

So, assuming you want to run from a Notes client we found that we had to write a jar file that runs on your workstation's JRE, (not IBM Lotus Notes' jvm), which was 1.6, and then make calls from the Notes client agent to run a batch file that executes the JAR with the workstations JRE. The separate JRE is making calls back to Notes to write data onto servers. This is very ugly, and technically we're not running under Notes any more, in fact we're running a separate java process, that is launched by Notes. When it comes to s/w, IBM make half-baked stuff or "space shuttles to get the milk", but you still have an obligation to stay current if you want to use their tech.

If you do elect this painful approach, you will need to enable "Don't prompt for a password from other Notes-based programs", which is in your "User Security" settings under "Security Basics".

So, tell your manager to bite the bullet and upgrade.

Comment: If work arounds could be classified by populations in the world, this is the "China" workaround. More sense to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any version of Java that you want for standalone programs, but if you need to run as an agent inside the Notes client or Domino server you are unfortunately stuck with the version that is supported by IBM and integrated into their code.

Comment: yes that is what i was trying to figure out. I wan to use it in an agent. Now I need to figure some other way round. Thanks for help..

Comment: The problem you may face with a standalone program is that the Notes.jar / NCSO.jar are only certified against the same JVM the Notes client supports. So while they may work in later JVMs, it is not a given. You may have to write out your answer to a file and pass it back to the agent.